# Highstock, make yAxis as zero

Tags: highcharts

I have the following scatter plot graph, I want to create the graph as such that there is no yaxis and all the scatter plots on the x-axis are seen as a straight line in both the graphs.

following is the fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/pratik24/n24s2fyk/1/

Code snippet:

```
$(function () {  
    $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {

        navigator:{
            enabled: false
        },
        scrollbar:{
            enabled: false
        },

         rangeSelector : {
            selected : 1,
             enabled:false
        },

        yAxis: [{
            labels: {
                align: 'left'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'OHLC'
            },
            height: '60%'
        }, {
            labels: {
                align: 'left',
                x: -3
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Volume'
            },
            top: '65%',
            height: '35%',
            offset: 0
        }],

        series: [{
            type: 'scatter',
            name: 'AAPL',
            data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.4, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]               
        }, {
            type: 'scatter',
            name: 'Volume',
            data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.4, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6],
              yAxis: 1

        }]
    });
```

});
How can this be achieved in HighStock,

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scatter points in straight line - set data that will be presented like this (e.g. [1,1,1,1,1]) or increase y axis scale using `min` and `max`

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/6bkzxoff/

To hide y axis use axis options:

```
        title: {
            text: ''
        },
        labels: {
            format: ' '
        }
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/6bkzxoff/1/

Comment: how can I make xaxis show values here, converting all yaxis values to xaxis.

Comment: Highstock doesn't support inverted chart that would switch x axis with y axis. You could change what is displayed in x axis labels using formatter - [API](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.labels.formatter)